# Inserting Data into an Oracle Table

Tags: r, database, oracle

I am very new to R, so please forgive any obvious or naive errors. I need to insert multiple rows of data from R into an Oracle database table.

Make the data frame (I have made the RJDBC connection earlier in the script):

```
df <- data.frame("field_1" = 1:2, "field_2" = c("f","k"), "field_3"= c("j","t"))
```

This code runs without error, but inserts only the first row into the table:

```
insert <- sprintf("insert into temp_r_test_u_suck values (%s')", 
                  apply(df, 1, function(i) gsub(" ", "", paste("'", i, collapse="',"), fixed = TRUE)))
dbSendUpdate(con, insert)
```

This code runs:

```
insert <- sprintf("into temp_r_test_u_suck values (%s')", 
                  apply(df, 1, function(i) gsub(" ", "", paste("'", i, collapse="',"), fixed = TRUE)))
insert_all <- c("insert all", insert, "select * from dual")
dbSendUpdate(con, insert_all)
```

But gives me this error:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  execute JDBC update query failed in dbSendUpdate (ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Both of the queries work on their own in Oracle. WHAT am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Please read about how to format questions so that code (and data) stand out (fixed width, etc): https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. I've made changes here, it helps the first-glance view of the question and \*might\* get you better/faster answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple SQL statements are not supported in `dbGetQuery`, `dbSendQuery`, `dbSendUpdate` calls. You need to iterate through them for each statement. Hence, why only the first statement processes. To resolve, extend the anonymous function inside `apply` to call `dbSendUpdate`:

```
apply(df, 1, function(i) {
      # BUILD SQL STATEMENT
      insert <- sprintf("insert into temp_r_test_u_suck values (%s')", 
                        paste0("'", i, collapse="',"))

      # RUN QUERY
      dbSendUpdate(con, insert)
})
```

However, RJDBC extends the DBI standard by supporting parameterization with `dbSendUpdate` as mentioned in [rForge docs](https://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/) for bulk-inserts with no need for iteratively concatenating strings.

> dbSendUpdate(conn, statement, ...) 
>  This function is analogous to
>   dbSendQuery, but works with DBML statements and thus doesn't return a
>   result set. It is more efficient than dbSendQuery. In addition, as of
>   RJDBC 0.2-9 it supports vectors in prepared statements which allows
>   bulk-inserts.

```
# ALL CHARACTER DATAFRAME
df <- data.frame(field_1=as.character(1:2), field_2=c("f","k"), field_3=c("j","t"), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql <- "insert into temp_r_test_u_suck values (?, ?, ?)"

# RUN QUERY
dbSendUpdate(con, sql, df$field_1, df$field_2, df$field_3)
```