# Inserting Data into a Vertica table (SQL) using R?

Tags: sql, r, vertica

I found a closely related article:
[Inserting Data into an Oracle Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886012/inserting-data-into-an-oracle-table)

I also need to insert a data frame with many rows to vertical, however, always got the same error (see below). Then I tried to insert my variables and got the same error. Can you help to solve the error?

```
# PREPARED STATEMENT
sql <- "INSERT INTO table (Date1,Date2,Group,Value) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"  

# RUN QUERY
dbSendUpdate(vertica, sql, as.Date("2021-03-03"), as.Date("2021-03-03"), "testing", 111)
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbSendUpdate’ for signature ‘"JDBCConnection", "function"’

Comment: Do you have JDBC driver for Vertica added to jour classpath?

Comment: Yes, it is added in dbSendUpdate(vertica part